# Can't read a .csv with python: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position..."

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv that looks like this:

*movies.csv*

```
MOVIE,YEAR,imdbID
One, two, three,2000,656565
Ieri, oggi, domani,2000,696969
Gladiator,2000,636363
...
```

It has a "," separator. I've tried to read this document with python 3 but I can't, with RStudio I don't have any problem though.

This is what I have:

```
  import csv
  import pandas as pd

  file = open("watched.csv")
  df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='utf-8')
```

And I get the following error:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 69269: character maps 
 to <undefined>
```

The commas in the movie name could be the problem? If that's so, how could I remove or replace them automatically?

Comment: Please send the output of `print(repr(pathlib.Path('watched.csv').read_bytes()[69260:69280]))`

Comment: This is the output: b'r-1985","tt0089767",'